# Why are .NET 3.5 & 4.7 handled differently in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, .net-framework, .net-3.5

Can anyone point to a definitive Microsoft resource explaining why .NET 3.5 and 4.7 use the new ***Turn Windows features on or off*** approach rather than a regular install? It seems strange that some versions get treated this way and some not. I have found plenty of references to HOW to install, from the manual Windows Features approach to automating with DISM and a network copy of the install media, but I have never found anything that explains WHY this is necessary.

This becomes an issue because companies like Autodesk still target these old versions of .NET, and their installers will try to install the old way, using a bundled EXE, which then fails and requires user interaction, which breaks the automated install. And why Microsoft makes this harder could help push Autodesk to stop targeting these old versions.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone point to a definitive Microsoft resource explaining why .NET 3.5 and 4.7 use the new Turn Windows features on or off approach rather than a regular install?

Starting with Windows 8 .NET Framework 3.5 was an optional Windows Feature. The version that came with Windows 8 could not be uninstalled only updated. .NET Framework 4.6 on Windows 8 and .NET Framework 3.5 are side by side configurations.

.NET Framework 4.0 is replaced by .NET 4.6 through .NET 4.8 which is the reason .NET Framework 3.5 is still an optional Windows Feature on Windows 10 and .NET Framework 4.8 is built-into the current version of Windows 10

> It seems strange that some versions get treated this way and some not. I have found plenty of references to HOW to install, from the manual Windows Features approach to automating with DISM and a network copy of the install media, but I have never found anything that explains WHY this is necessary.

.NET 4.6 through .NET 4.8 is built-into their respective Windows edition.  Any other supported editions of Windows for later versions of .NET can be manually installed.  As for the reason, Microsoft wanted to include the .NET Framework with Windows, in order to compete with Java.

> This becomes an issue because companies like Autodesk still target these old versions of .NET, and their installers will try to install the old way, using a bundled EXE, which then fails and requires user interaction, which breaks the automated install.

Sounds like you are using an older version of Autodesk, since an installer can enable the optional Windows Feature, if the application specifically targets .NET Framework 3.5 otherwise a capable version of the .NET Framework is either already installed or can be installed with the respective.NET stand-alone installer.

> And why Microsoft makes this harder could help push Autodesk to stop targeting these old versions.

Microsoft doesn’t make it harder, .NET applications are backwards compatible which means an application expecting .NET Framework 4.7 will run on a system with .NET Framework 4.8 without an issue.

Comment: This answer doesn’t contain a single opinion, everything I have stated is easily verified, by documentation by Microsoft.  It just isn’t required to refer to that documentation in order to answer that question.  I have been a .NET developer since before it was generally available to the public.  Just the other day I had an application prompt me to enable the optional Windows feature (.NET Framework 3.5).

Comment: unfortunately this is not an older version of Autodesk stuff. It is Revit and 3DS Max 2021, using their new deployment creation process. And it still doesn't install on Windows 10, which has been the case for years now. It triggers a manual download from the web, which is basically useless. I guess what I don't understand is, why don't the 3.5 and 4.7 installers that DO work silently on older Windows not still work in Windows 10? Why the different approach?

Comment: as for .NET 4.8, it does install, but some Autodesk stuff still demands 4.7.#, even when 4.8 is already there. It's not a Microsoft problem, it's an Autodesk problem, I know.

Comment: @Gordon .NET 4.7 and 3.5 cannot be installed by an installer on Windows 10.  .NET 4.8 is an in-place upgrade which means 4.7 cannot be installed on the same system.  A 4.7 application on a system with 4.8 absolutely should run, if it doesn’t, reach out to the vendor that isn’t a Microsoft problem nor one I will address in my answer